# Convertir tipo de dato en C#

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

espero me puedan ayudar.

Tengo un DataGridView que mostrará un listado de pacientes registrados previamente, al seleccionar una fila, envía esos datos a las cajas de texto respectivas (las cuales están deshabilitadas para edición), hasta ahí todo bien. Luego quedan solos dos cajas habilitadas para introducir más información, pero no tienen nada que ver con el Data. El uso del data es informativo, para que el usuario verifique que se ha seleccionado un paciente específico. al cual añadirá información (la que se va a otra tabla). Esta información añadida se guarda en otra tabla, pero me llevo el IdPaciente, para poder relacionar ambas tablas. Y aquí tengo el problema, en la clase Atención tengo el constructor:

```
public Atencion(decimal _peso, DateTime _fecha_atencion, Paciente _idPacienteFK)
    {
        this.peso = _peso;
        this.fecha_atencion = _fecha_atencion;
        this.idPacienteFK = _idPacienteFK;
    }
```

y los respectivos metodos set y get.

Luego en la clase AtencionBD tengo los metodos para guardar en este caso:

```
public void insertarAtencion()
    {
        if (this.cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            this.cn.Open();
        }
        MySqlCommand comandos = new MySqlCommand();
        comandos.Connection = this.cn;
        comandos.CommandText = "INSERT INTO atencion(idatencion, peso, fecha_atencion, estado, pacientes_idpacientes) VALUES(idatencion, @peso, @fecha_atencion, @estado, @pacientes_idpacientes)";
        comandos.Parameters.AddWithValue("@peso", this.atencion.PESO);
        comandos.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_atencion", this.atencion.FECHAATENCION);
        comandos.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estado", this.atencion.ESTADO);
        comandos.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pacientes_idpacientes", this.atencion.IDPACIENTEFK.IDPACIENTE);

        comandos.ExecuteNonQuery();
        this.cn.Close();
    }
```

(hay un item más que en el constructor, ese demás lo tengo para actualizar despues)

Ahora, el codigo del boton guardar es:

```
private void icoBtnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal Peso = Convert.ToDecimal(this.txtPeso.Text);
        DateTime fechaAtencion = Convert.ToDateTime(this.dtpFechaAtencion.Value);
        Paciente idPaciente = (Paciente)Convert.ToInt32(dgvPacientes.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);



        DialogResult dialogo = MessageBox.Show("Se guardarán los datos, ¿Está seguro?", "Mensaje de pregunta", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (dialogo == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            atencion = new Atencion(Peso, fechaAtencion, idPaciente);
            atencion.insertarAtencion();
            MessageBox.Show("Atención Agregada Correctamente", "Informacion de Atención", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            limpiarCampos();

        }
    }
```

Y es aquí donde tengo el problema, pues me arroja un error. Me dice que no puede convertir el tipo "int" en Paciente.

Si alguíen me puede ayudar por favor.

Comment: Podrías proporcionar por favor el código / ejemplo de cómo se llena el datagridview, según entiendo idPaciente viene en la primera columna, habría que verificar que el dato en la primera columna sea coherente con el tipo de dato al qué quieres convertir (int32 en este caso)

Comment: pues no puedes convertir un tipo pacienteId en variable paciente asi es como lo tienes declarado. Paciente pacienteId , puedes declarar Paciente paciente= new Paciente(); despues asignar la propiedad id a este objeto   paciente.id = Convert.ToInt32(dgvPacientes.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);

Comment: @MiguelZarate gracias, efectivamente tu respuesta me solucionó el problema. Ahora no se como marcarla como la respuesta correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Estas instanciando un objeto (paciente) y luego casteas paciente y conviertes el dato en int32 creo que debes realizar lo siguiente

```
int idPaciente = Convert.ToInt32(dgvPacientes.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
```

prueba utilizando un punto de control y ver que te arroja el valor de dgvPacientes.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value